# How to access one column of a table corresponding to two different columns of another table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch column EmployeeName from Table A associated with toEmployeeId and fromEmployeeId in Table B using one query only.

Here are my tables

```
Table A
|---------------------|------------------|
|    Employeeid       |  EmployeeName    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          E1         |       ABC1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          E2         |       ABC2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          E3         |       ABC3       |
|---------------------|------------------|

Table B
|---------------------|------------------|
|    toEmployeeid     |  fromEmployeeid  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          E1         |       E3         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          E2         |       E1         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          E3         |       E1         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Here is the query I am trying to run but it is not working

```
select A.Employeeid, A.employeename,
      (select employeename
       from A,
            B
       where A.employeeid = B.fromemployeeid)
from A,
     B
where B.toEmployeeid = A.id;
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it to work. For anyone looking for an answer.

```
select At.Employeeid, At.employeename,
      (select employeename from A as At
       where At.employeeid = Bt.fromemployeeid) as fromEmpId
from A as At,
     B as Bt
where Bt.toEmployeeid = At.Employeeid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same table A two time  with proper alias A1 e A2

```
select B.toEmployeeid
    , A1.EmployeeName
    ,  B.fromEmployeeid
    , A2.EmployeeName
from B
INNER JOIN  A A1  ON A1.Employeeid = B.toEmployeeid
INNER JOIN  A A2  ON A2.Employeeid = B.fromEmployeeid
```